# spots on wood panel

Tags: paint, fungus

[image]

I noticed a number of spots on my house wooden wall that lost paints. Fungus infection? How to treat? Thanks.

Comment: Lost paint or covering the paint?  Try a simple wipe with a damp(water) cloth.  Let us know how easy or hard it comes off.

Comment: Is this a dry, crusty pile of "stuff"? I'm willing to bet you can just scratch it off with a finger nail or the edge of a credit card. Maybe hold a paper towel tight against the wall below it or hold the hose of the vacuum up to catch the crud as it falls off.

Comment: What's  the time frame in noticing the spots?

Comment: Is the spot a bulge? Is this wood paneling that scratch makes it look like real wood. Is this inside in a heated cooled space or like on a back porch? If a fungus hydrogen peroxide 3% will kill it but it may affect the wood color if real and if a paper covered MDF type product moisture may make it worse.